# How overwrite optflags direct in rpm spec file?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

How correct overwrite `%optflags` direct in spec file ?

```
$ rpm --eval %optflags   # Fedora 29
-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection
```

I need replace `-O2` by `-O` in `%optflags` macro direct in my **spec file** ? I found only this one solution:

```
%global optflags %(echo %{optflags} | sed 's/-O[0-3]/-O/')
```

It is correct ?

Note `rpmbuild -ba --define "optflags -O bla bla" my.spec` it is not a solution for my case.

Comment: I think is the correct, since everyone use it:I also didn't find other (good) solution.
` optflags=$(sed 's/-O2/-O/g' <<< "%{build_cflags}") `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%{optflags}` macro, works as a wrapper with many other macros on it. The `-O2` is an individual compiler flag which usually can be defined in `CFLAGS`.

When running `rpm --showrc|grep '\-O2'` we can see it is part of the macro `_general_options`.
So you can adjust it in the spec file as:

```
%define _general_options -O
```

The `%{optflags}` will inherit this macro and as result the `-O2` will become `-O`

Alternatively you can use:

```
%define _general_option  -O %{?_lto_cflags} -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe
```

This way, you will keep everything but just change the `-O2` flag

A good reference is the [buildflags](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/redhat-rpm-config//blob/rawhide/f/buildflags.md) documentation

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have found part of the solution already. To check whether it is correct you could temporarily put

```
echo %optflags
```

To print the value once inside your spec file or

```
%dump
```

To dump all macros (not sure whether optflags will be printed this way)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to replace `-O2` in the optflags to effectively use `-O`. You just need to append `-O` to the optflags because gcc only considers the last occurrence of a `-O` option:

> If you use multiple -O options, with or without level numbers, the last
> such option is the one that is effective.

[gcc(1)](https://manpath.be/f32/gcc/10.1.1-1.fc32.x86_64/1/gcc#L7379)

Thus, you don't need to shell-out and can simply append `-O` like this:

```
%global optflags %{optflags} -O
```

You can verify this approach by resolving all macros with `rpmspec`, e.g.:

```
$ rpmspec -P example.spec
```